# Does logbook have an equivalent to logging.config.fileConfig?

Tags: python, logging, logbook

Python's built-in `logging` module has a [`fileConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig) method that allows passing a config parser in to actually setup all the logging handlers.

Is there a way to do something similar with [`logbook`](https://logbook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)? As yet I've been unable to find any documented behavior like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Logbook doesn't have this functionality at the moment.